# Head first servlets & JSP example doesn't work

Tags: java, eclipse, servlets

I’m reading the book "`Head first servlets & JSP`" and using `tomcat 9`, `jdk8`,`eclipse neon`.The `servlet` is not working.I am getting an error:"`HTTP Status 500 - Error instantiating servlet class com.example.web.BeerSelect`"

The picture is my workspace.

[my workspace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RDF72.png)

this is my `HTML` code.(`form.html`)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>beer</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1 align = "center">Beer Selection Page</h1>
<form method="POST" action="SelectBeer.do">
 Select beer characteristics<p>
 Color:
 <select name="color" size = "1">
  <option value="light">light</option>
  <option value="amber">amber</option>
  <option value="brown">brown</option>
  <option value="dark">dark</option>
 </select>
 <br><br>
 <center>
  <input type="SUBMIT">
 </center>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

this is my `web.xml`

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">

  <servlet>
   <servlet-name>Ch3 Beer</servlet-name>
   <servlet-class>com.example.web.BeerSelect</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  
  <servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>Ch3 Beer</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>/SelectBeer.do</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

This is my `servlet`(`BeerSelect.java`)

```html
package com.example.web;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;


@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class BeerSelect extends HttpServlet{

 public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException,ServletException
 {
  response.setContentType("text/html");
  PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
  
  out.println("Beer Selection Advice<br>");
  String c = request.getParameter("color");
  out.println("<br>Got beer color " + c);
 }
}
```

`.class` is not generated.What's wrong with it.

Comment: what is location of BeerSelect.class file where you put it

Comment: it's not generate.i think it will be generate automatically.So how can i generate it in the eclipse.

Comment: Do you have more of that stack trace, preferably from the server log? What you've shown doesn't indicate that the class file is missing. Off hand, try a servlet name without whitespace in it.

Comment: the class file is missing indeed.the solution is set the classpath.i forgot it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm I can't see the `.class` file in your workspace. This is just a suggestion but you could try compiling the `servlet` java file by using

```
 javac BeerSelect.java
```

This should create a `BeerSelect.class` file. Then create a `classes` folder and put it in there. Like this:

```
WebContent/WEB-INF/classes/com/example/web/BeerSelect.class
```

See if that helps at all.

Comment: thank you,it worked! But how can i generate it in the eclipse

Comment: Try using Project -> Build All (Ctrl + B) in Eclipse. I think that should compile the .java files

Comment: this button is grey.So i search the Internet.i found that javac is not work.thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You will not see `.class` files in `eclipse`. And while creating your project you may not changed your class file folder, the default is `build/classes`.And its not mandatory to change your `class` file folder path unless you want to keep them in your desired place. You can see the `class` file in your workspace. 
And related to your code nothing wrong in the code, it is working fine. Just one change I made to load html as homepage. I added below lines in your `web.xml`.

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>form.html</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
```

And it's working fine.

Comment: @Saxon try this, undeploy your project from server and clean the project. Build it again and deploy and restart the server. And please check any import errors are there.

Comment: oh，it's ok.i'm forgot set my classpath and the commond "javac" is not work.Thank you very much.